# Why did the writer of the 2016 "Lucifer" comic series change from Holly Black to Richard Kadrey?

Tags: comics, holly-black, lucifer, richard-kadrey

I've been following the 2016 *Lucifer* series, and enjoying it. While re-arranging my Calibre library, I noticed that, while all the issues up to and including 12th have been written by Holly Black, issue 13 was written by Black *and* Richard Kadrey, while all issues after that were written by Kadrey alone.

[image: Issue #13]  [image: Issue #14]  [image: Issue #15]
 <sub>Click for full resolution.</sub>

The original *Lucifer* comic series was written by Mike Carey alone. *The Sandman* was written by Neil Gaiman alone. While a rotating cast of artists is a known thing in comics, especially in *The Sandman* and the new *Lucifer* series (though not so much in Mike Carey's series), I didn't know of a series that would change the writer in the middle of the run, and especially in the middle of an arc.

I know some other comics do it, but I expected *Lucifer* to be held to a higher standard. **What is the reason the writer was changed mid-series?** Was it a pre-mediated decision, or was it because of a disagreement over the process (which seems unlikely since Black and Kadrey did an issue together)?

Comment: The most I can find only implies it was amicable, and at least somewhat pre-meditated; [they did press on the handoff](http://www.comicsbeat.com/nycc-16-author-richard-kadrey-to-take-over-lucifer-with-issue-13/), but I can't find any comments on the reasons.  I did stumble on a mention (unsourced, so *shrug) that she was reluctant to do a monthly comic series, perhaps a year was enough.

Comment: @Radhil That's good to read - looks like at least it wasn't a violent break-up with Vertigo on Black's part. Thank you!